# Error: The size of tensor a (892) must match the size of tensor b (400) at non-singleton dimension 3

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I am building Auto-encoder model in image dataset which has the shape of (3,347,400) using by pytorch,I am facing the above error when i try to train my model
Here is my Encoder and decoder model

```py
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()        
       self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
           nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, stride=2, padding=1),
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1),
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 7) 
       )
       
      
       self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 7), 
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, 3, stride=3,padding=1), 
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 3, 3, stride=3,padding=1), 
           nn.Sigmoid()
       )

   def forward(self, x):
       encoded = self.encoder(x)
       decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
       return decoded
```

For the loss I am using MSE(), can anyone please help me this ?

Comment: Can you upload the MSE code? And also shape of label.

Comment: model = Autoencoder()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),
                             lr=1e-3, 
                             weight_decay=1e-5) .. this is my loss , can you please help me to define me the structure of the Auto-encoder ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of when making an autoencoder is that the input shape and the output shape should be the same.

Autoencoder consists of a part that **compresses input information** (`encoder`) and a part that **converts compressed information into original input** (`decoder`). Therefore, the shape of the input and the shape of the output must be the same.

I modified your autoencoder a bit to match the input shape and output shape. This code will help you understand.

This code use [torch.nn.functional.pad](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.pad.html) to match the input shape and output shape.

Code:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()        
       self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
           nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, stride=2, padding=1),
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1),
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 7) 
       )
      
       self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 7), 
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, 3, stride=2, padding=1), 
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 3, 3, stride=2, padding=1), 
           nn.Sigmoid()
       )

   def forward(self, x):
       encoded = self.encoder(x)
       decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
       # use torch.nn.functional.pad
       output = F.pad(decoded, (1,2,1,1), "constant", 0)
       return output

x = torch.randn(3,347,400)
model = Autoencoder()
# When you modify the model, the output should be the same as the shape of x.
print(model(x).shape)
```

Or you can make the input shape and the output shape the same by adjusting the stride or padding values as follows.

Code:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()        
       self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
           nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 7) 
       )
      
       self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 7), 
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, 3, stride=1, padding=1), 
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 3, 3, stride=1, padding=1), 
           nn.Sigmoid()
       )

   def forward(self, x):
       encoded = self.encoder(x)
       decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
       return decoded

model = Autoencoder()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3, weight_decay=1e-5)

x = torch.randn(3,347,400)
# When you modify the model, the output should be the same as the shape of x.
print(model(x).shape)
```

And both results are the same

Result:

```
torch.Size([3, 347, 400])
```

Comment: Highly appreciated !,  
num_epochs = 5
outputs = []
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for (img, _) in train_data_loader:
        
        recon = model(img)
        loss = criterion(recon, img)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print(f'Epoch:{epoch+1}')
    outputs.append((epoch, img, recon))  .. using by your above Auto-encoder i try to train my model but will take too much time , is there anything i need to change my for loop train please , Thanks

Comment: Are you using a GPU? If not, this [document](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html) might be helpful for you. And increasing the batch size may reduce the time slightly.